# Split cell to lines for multiple lines

Tags: microsoft-excel

Basically I have this table format:

```
Id  |   Order content
----+------------------------------------
01  |   Item 1, Item 2, Item 3
----+------------------------------------
02  |   Item 1
----+------------------------------------
03  |   Item 1, Item 2
```

What I need is to push down the lines and put all items one per line like so

```
Id  |   Order content
----+------------------------------------
01  |   Item 1
    |   Item 2
    |   Item 3
----+------------------------------------
02  |   Item 1
----+------------------------------------
03  |   Item 1
    |   Item 2
```

The closest thing for this is Kutools which has a function that does this but only for 1 cell and I need it for about 2000 lines where some lines can contain any number of order items.

Please advise

Comment: Does `ID 01` `Item 2` need to be in cell `B3`, and `Item 3` into `B4`? Or can the item list be multi-line inside `B2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Position your cursor in the table
2. Use Data>From Table/Range
3. In the PowerQuery Editor, select the 'Order Content' column and use Split>By Delimiter, being sure to set the delimiter to 'Comma'
4. Use Shift+Click to select all of the 'Order Content.X' columns
5. Use Transform>Unpivot>Unpivot Only Selected Columns
6. Select the Attribute column, right-click and select 'Remove'
7. Optional: Select the Value column, right-click and select Transform>Trim (to remove leading or trailing spaces)
8. Use Home>Close & Load to put the transformed table back onto the workbook in a new sheet

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort of providing the video as well. Much appreciated and a ton of workhours saved.

Answer (score 1):

Select your Order Content column and then Replace (CTRL-H) your commas with ALT-SHIFT-J. This will replace commas with a new line. This is assuming you want all orders to be in the same cell for each ID.

[image]